# converting data frame into affiliation network in R

Tags: r, igraph, sna

I have a data frame with the following format:

```
name workplace
a     A
b     B
c     A
d     C
e     D
....
```

I would like to convert this data frame into an affiliation network in R with the format

```
    A B C D ...
a   1 0 0 0
b   0 1 0 0
c   1 0 0 0
d   0 0 1 0
e   0 0 0 1
...
```

and I used the following program:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(A1)) {  
  a1[rownames(a1) == A1$name[i],
     colnames(a1) == A1$workplace[i]] <- 1
}
```

where A1 is the data frame, and a1 is the affiliation network. However, since I have a large data frame, the above program runs very slow. Is there an efficient way that avoids looping in data conversion?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data called `df` just do:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))
#   A B C D
# a 1 0 0 0
# b 0 1 0 0
# c 1 0 0 0
# d 0 0 1 0
# e 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: This is really cool. BTW, I have a longitudinal network so after this data transformation the column dimensions are not the same across years, e.g. one year has 1000 columns and another year has 2000 columns. What I want to do is to make the column dimensions of all the matrices across years the same. How would you do that? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Can you provide an actual example?

Comment: Sure. After I did your command as the following:
for (i in 0:18) {
  a <- eval(parse(text=paste0("A",i)))
  assign(x=paste0("df", i), value =  as.data.frame.matrix(table(a[,-3])))  
  
}

Comment: No, I mean provide an actual data that this solution want work with correctly

Comment: Sure. I got 19 matrices of the same row number but different column numbers. e.g. df1 is 
   A  B  C
a  1  0  0
b  0  1  0
c  1  0  0
d  0  0  1

and df2 is 
   A  B  D
a  1  0  0
b  0  1  0
c  1  0  0
d  0  0  0

How do I convert both df1 and df2 to matrices that have 4 columns and 4 rows such as 
  A  B  C  D
a
b
c
d

Comment: sorry for the matrix format. the row names are a b c d, and column names are A B C and A B D.

Comment: It's not so clear from your comment. Maybe ask a new question and link to hear

Comment: Sorry that the previous comments were not clear. I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785605/paste-matrix-in-r. Hope this will clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be this also helps:

```
 m1 <- model.matrix(~0+workplace, data=dat)
 dimnames(m1) <- lapply(dat, unique)
 as.data.frame(m1)
 #  A B C D
 #a 1 0 0 0
 #b 0 1 0 0
 #c 1 0 0 0
 #d 0 0 1 0
 #e 0 0 0 1
```