# Paste matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a question regarding pasting matrices. I have a set of 10 matrices with the same row name but different column names, e.g.

matrix 1:

```
   A B C D
a  1 0 0 0
b  0 1 0 0
c  0 1 0 0
d  0 0 1 0 
e  0 0 0 1
```

matrix 2:

```
  A B D E F
a 1 0 0 0 0
b 0 1 0 0 0
c 0 1 0 0 0 
d 0 0 0 0 0
e 0 0 1 0 0
```

I would like to format both matrices as

```
  A B C D E F
a 1 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 1 0 0 0 0
c 0 1 0 0 0 0
d 0 0 1 0 0 0
e 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

How can I do it quickly in R without looping?
Thanks!

Comment: What if a column appears in more than one matrix, like `A` here. Are we to assume the values will always be the same? What if they differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample data:

```
mat1 <- data.matrix(read.table(text="A B C D
a  1 0 0 0
b  0 1 0 0
c  0 1 0 0
d  0 0 1 0 
e  0 0 0 1", header = TRUE, row.names = 1))

mat2 <- data.matrix(read.table(text="A B D E F
a 1 0 0 0 0
b 0 1 0 0 0
c 0 1 0 0 0 
d 0 0 0 0 0
e 0 0 1 0 0", header = TRUE, row.names = 1))
```

Let's assume you have all your matrices in a list (if not, create one)

```
mat.list <- list(mat1, mat2)
```

Our first step is to convert the matrices to data.frames. This will make the algorithm make an efficient use of memory:

```
df.list <- lapply(mat.list, as.data.frame)
```

We write a function to merge two data.frames:

```
cat.df <- function(d1, d2) {d1[names(d2)] <- d2; d1}
```

We merge all the data.frames iteratively, into one big data.frame:

```
one.df <- Reduce(cat.df, df.list)
```

Finally, we convert it to a matrix:

```
one.mat <- data.matrix(one.df)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether there will be any difference in speed if you use a `for` loop.  Using a couple more matrices along with @flodel's dataset

```
mat3 <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), c("A", "B", 
"D", "G", "H")))

mat4 <- structure(c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), c("B", "C", 
"D", "H", "I")))

lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern="^mat\\d+"))

  mRes <- lst1[[1]]
  for(i in seq_along(lst1)){
  indx <- setdiff(colnames(lst1[[i]]), colnames(mRes))
  mRes <-cbind(mRes, lst1[[i]][,indx, drop=FALSE])
  mRes
  }  

   mRes
 #  A B C D E F G H I
 #a 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
 #b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 #c 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
 #d 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
 #e 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```