# data frame to affiliation matrix in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

`HAVE` is a data frame with this structure:

```
name workplace pr_happy
a     A            0.93
b     B            0.54
c     A            0.72
d     C            0.17
e     D            0.44
```

I `WANT` to build an adjacency matrix of name and workplace (exactly like this question: [converting data frame into affiliation network in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780309/converting-data-frame-into-affiliation-network-in-r)), but instead of a matrix with binary values, I want the values of `pr_happy` to populate the cells for each affiliation. `WANT` should look like this:

```
       A    B    C    D 
a   0.93 0.00 0.00 0.00
b   0.00 0.54 0.00 0.00
c   0.72 0.00 0.00 0.00
d   0.00 0.00 0.17 0.00
e   0.00 0.00 0.00 0.44
```

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around a way to do this simply. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially pivoting and replacing `NA` values

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  spread(workplace, pr_happy, fill = 0) %>% # thank you @Jordo82
  tibble::column_to_rownames("name")

     A    B    C    D
a 0.93 0.00 0.00 0.00
b 0.00 0.54 0.00 0.00
c 0.72 0.00 0.00 0.00
d 0.00 0.00 0.17 0.00
e 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.44
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                      workplace = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "D"),
                      pr_happy = c(0.93, 0.54, 0.72, 0.17, 0.44)),
                 .Names = c("name", "workplace", "pr_happy"),
                 row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

Comment: You call also use the `fill` argument in spread to replace NA's with 0: `spread(workplace, pr_happy, fill = 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like that :

```
WANT=matrix(data = 0,nrow = 5,ncol = 4)
rownames(WANT)=letters[1:5]
colnames(WANT)=LETTERS[1:4]

for ( i in 1:5){
   WANT[HAVE[i,1],HAVE[i,2]]=HAVE[i,3]
}
```

(although I am sure there is a way without the loop)

Comment: Making some assumptions (`name` and `workplace` columns are factors, the order of the levels of the factors is the same as the row and column orders in `WANT`), then we can use matrix indexing to avoid the `for` loop. Call the input data frame `df`, then `HAVE = sapply(df, as.numeric)` and `WANT[HAVE[, 1:2]] = HAVE[, 3]` does the assignment without a loop.

Comment: These assumptions are pretty easy to enforce, just make your `rownames(WANT) = levels(df$name); colnames(WANT) = levels(df$workplace)`.